# The Difference Between the Words Woman and Wife

Tags: vocabulary

In my mother tongue, Persian, the words 'wife' and 'woman' mean the same, that is, somebody that is married to a man (of course I mean their literal translation in the Persian language). However, woman is an informal word. I'm wondering if the word woman has the same meaning in English as that of wife.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, no. "woman" in English just means any female of the human race, though it's more commonly used to refer to older women who have gone through puberty (prepubescent women are usually called girls instead). "wife" is only used when the woman is married.